# Xcode content starts at the same position then navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, view, swift3

everytime I fill my ViewContorller with content it starts at the same position then my navigation bar. That means the content is alway cutted and its not possible to see the start of that content.

This is how it looks like:[image]

For example over the header there is a name for that rows "SECTION1".
How can I fix that?
I used eureka forms here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `isTranslucent` property of `UINavigationBar` to `false` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed. May there be a mistake in my storyboard?

Comment: @luki512 Try this one also `self.navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

Comment: @luki512 Welcome mate :)